# How to get return value from insert query defined in @query annotation

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two tables city and shape, where city has composite primary key as(City and country) and one auto generated Id value. This Id is foreign key for Shape.
So after insertion of data in city table, I want Id that was inserted to be used in shape table. I have used Spring boot with jpa and postgres

In CityRepository I have custom save method which will do nothing on conflict.

I have tried below code to get returned value. But I get Error 
SqlExceptionHelper   : A result was returned when none was expected.

How to get the returning value from insert query?

```
@Modifying
@Query(value="insert into public.city_info(city, country) values(:city,:country) on conflict do nothing returning city_id",nativeQuery = true)
@Transactional
Integer save(@Param("city")String city,@Param("country") String country);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid but that's not possible with JPA.

If you look at the JPA Query API:

```
int executeUpdate()

Execute an update or delete statement.

Returns: the number of entities updated or deleted
```

There is no other return value possible.